# Adding options to a select from an object? (JS)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Trying to build a currency converter app, but I'm having trouble with adding options to a select element. I want to have the name (USD) and value (1.23) in the option.
I tried to convert the object to array to use map but didnt seem to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

HTML

```
<div id="msg"></div>
<input type="number" autofocus id="input">
<select id="rateFrom">
</select>
 <hr>
<input type="number" disabled id="output">
<select id="rateTo">
</select>
```

JS

```
const select = document.getElementById('rateFrom'); 
const url = 'https://api.fixer.io/latest?base=USD'; // get currency rates
fetch(url)
.then(response => {
    if (response.status !=200) {
        document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML=`<p>SYSTEM IS OFFLINE 
(${response.status})</p>`
    }else{
        return response.json();
    }
})
.then(data => {
    console.log(data);
 document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML=`<p>SYSTEM IS ONLINE (LAST UPDATE 
 WAS @ ${data.date})</p>`
 let rates = data.rates;
 console.log(rates);
 rates = Object.keys(rates).map(function (key) {  //convert object to array
 return { [key]: rates[rates] };
 })
 console.log(rates);
 return rates.map(function(rate) { // map through the rates and for each run 
 the code below


let el = document.createElement("option");
 el.textContent = rate;
 el.value = rate;
 select.appendChild(el);
 })
 })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had some number of mistakes in your `.then` try the below it displays name + value in the option

```js
const select = document.getElementById('rateFrom'); 
const url = 'https://api.fixer.io/latest?base=USD'; // get currency rates

fetch(url)
.then(response => {
    if (response.status !=200) {
        document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML=`<p>SYSTEM IS OFFLINE (${response.status})</p>`
    }else{
        return response.json();
    }
})
.then(data => {
      document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML=`<p>SYSTEM IS ONLINE (LAST UPDATE WAS @ ${data.date})</p>`

      let rates = data.rates;

      // data from url doesn't have USD 1.23 like you mentioned in your question, 
      // but if you want to add it manually do this:
      let usdOption = document.createElement("option");
      usdOption.value = 'USD';
      usdOption.textContent = 'USD '+1.23;
      select.add(usdOption)

      // populating options with data from the url
      Object.keys(rates).map(function (key) {
   let el = document.createElement("option");
       el.value = key;
   el.textContent = key + ' ' + rates[key];
    select.add(el)
     })
 })
```

```html
<div id="msg"></div>
<input type="number" autofocus id="input">
<select id="rateFrom">
</select>
 <hr>
<input type="number" disabled id="output">
<select id="rateTo">
</select>
```

Comment: Another question, I want to do the same for the second select (#rateTo) I thought using querySelectorAll() but it returns a NodeList, any thoughts on the best way to implement it?  https://jsbin.com/gatihereqe/edit?html,js,output

Comment: You want to add the same data to #rateTo?

Comment: Yes, I need the same data.

Comment: just create a new 'select' for 'rateTo' just like you have for 'rateFrom' and inside .then instead of just adding to your original select add to your new select as well

Comment: yh you don't need to duplicate everything, just re-use the same element:  selectFrom.add(el) selectTo.add(el);

Comment: sorry my mistake that shouldn't work, you can leave your code as you had before or if you want to make it neater you can copy the first select and assign it to the other one, i.e. outside of the Object.keys mapping function do this:                
                selectTo.innerHTML = selectFrom.innerHTML;

Answer (score 0):

use `select.add(el);` instead of `select.appendChild(el);`

Comment: does it matter if you use `add` instead of  `appendChild`?

Answer (score 0):

Try out the code below to form the appropriate data structure that you require.

```
rates = Object.keys(rates).map(function (key) { 
            return { [key]: rates[key] } 
     });
```

In your append to HTML part,

```
let currentKey = Object.keys(rate)[0]; 

el.textContent = currentKey;

el.value = rate[currentKey];
```

Hope that helps.